# Simulink: Control Variant Subsystems Using Mask

Tags: matlab, simulink, masking

I would like to find a simple process for switching the model innards under a mask using the mask parameters.

**This question has expanded enough such that it has been reimplemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629344/simulink-control-variant-subsystems-using-mask-2-0).**

Variant subsystems are an excellent method and can be controlled via workspace parameters;
however, I have found mask parameters to not interface with the variant subsystem selection.

[This link](http://blogs.mathworks.com/simulink/2008/08/13/dynamic-mask-dialogs/) is the first of a series of posts on how to use mask parameters to make changes to blocks inside of the system;
however, the method is not as intuitive as using variant subsystems and a switch.
The link is also from 2008 and I believe that it may have been superceded at some point.

### MWE

I have made a model containing a system labeled `Source`.
It is connected to a `Display` block which displays its output.

`Source` is a variant subsystem.
It contains 3 variants:

- `Source\One`
- `Source\Two`
- `Source\Three`.

Each variant contains one `Constant` block.
The value of the `Constant` block is eponymous with the block label.
*For example,* `Source\Two` contains a constant block with value `2`.

`Source` is also a masked subsystem.
Its mask contains a `Radio Button` parameter with a value labeled `variantValue`.
The `Radio Button` options for the `variantValue` parameter are:

- Choice 1
- Choice 2
- Choice 3

The mask `Initialization` code is as follows:

```
switch variantValue

case 'Choice 1'
set_param('Source','OverrideUsingVariant','One')
disp('One')

case 'Choice 2'
set_param('Source','OverrideUsingVariant','Two')

case 'Choice 3'
set_param('Source','OverrideUsingVariant','Three')

end
```

I have set the variant to Override.
I cannot set the mask to allow library blocks to modify contents, as this is greyed out.

I will drop the variant subsystem deeper into the hierarchy from the masked subsystem when a masked subsystem which is a variant subsystem works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do anything which does not go via your base workspace, you first need to set the "Overwrite variant conditions...", now you can choose the active variant with code:

```
set_param('untitled/Variant Subsystem','OverrideUsingVariant','Variant1')
```

What remains is creating a mask which, whenever the parameter is changed in your mask, runs the above line. This can be done via the initialisation commands.

Comment: Added question: does all of this work in real-time applications.  (Not asking to change model blocks during run-time, but if this setup is constructed, would it build with whichever subsystem is set and upload to and function on a target?)

Comment: It should work for real time systems as well. I would expect the generated code to contain only the selected variant.

Comment: Continuing question: What if the variant system is embedded as follows: `Masked Subsytem (with the Variant Switch in the mask) --> Subsystem --> Unrelated Masked Subsytem --> Variant Subsytem`.  Will there be any problems?

Comment: @kando: I don't expect any problem, just try it. If you hit any limitation or error come back with a new question.

Comment: I'm currently trying `set_param('Variant Subsystem','OverrideUsingVariant','Variant1')` with no luck.  Can the Variant System be the masked system?

Comment: Did you set the "Overwrite variant conditions..." flag? What problems do you have?

Comment: Added in the question. I did.

Comment: I am not sure how you defined your mask, is `variantValue` really a char? I would expect a double. When using `switch` it is typically good practice to insert `otherwise` with an `error` if you expect it to never happen.

Comment: I just tried it and confirmed it is working. Not sure where your problem is.

Comment: Did you need to define variantValue as a char? I stated everything I did, so if you did anything extra, I'd like to know.

Comment: I tried it with `switch 1` `switch 2` and it worked.

Comment: This was a problem I was having with the Radio Button documentation.  I could not find anything in the documentation which specified the output of a given selection.  Since the options are strings and the listed selection is listed as that string, I assumed that the selected string was the output. Many thanks.

Comment: The mask is intended to alter a library variant subsystem multiple levels down the path.  Several copies of the library block exist.  Do I need to set the variantOverride parameter in the upper mask for each copy of the library variant, or should I set the Radio Button in the upper mask and then mask the variant system and initialize it to set the variantOverride there (using the Radio Button parameter from above)?

Comment: All subsystems should have the same variant chosen?

Comment: The mask Radio Button is intended to select the variant for a library variant subsystem. Several copies of the library block exist within the mask. Do I need to code the mask initialization to setParameter for each copy of the library variant under the mask? Or should I make the Radio Button in the upper mask and then mask the variant system and initialize the variant subsystem to setParameter for itself (easy with gcb) with the radio button from above as an input? The latter is more general and preferred, but I fear a disconnect - upper mask selections may require a manual model refresh.

Comment: Yes; all subsystems within the top-level mask have the same variant. (But multiple copies of the top level mask will exist in the model overall, each with a different radio button selection, which should convert all of subsystems it contains).

Comment: " Or should I make the Radio Button in the upper mask and then mask the variant system and initialize the variant subsystem to setParameter for itself (easy with gcb) with the radio button from above" That is the way to go. Your variable from the top level mask (`variantValue`) will be propagated downwards and can be used in the lower level mask initialisation code.

Comment: If I change the parameter in the upper level mask, will I need to Update Model for the changes to take effect?

Comment: Also, the variant mask initialization is not reading variantValue. Do I need something like a `get_parameter` command?

Comment: This question has been reimplemented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629344/simulink-control-variant-subsystems-using-mask-2-0).

Comment: Okay now I realize where the flaw in my suggestion was. Had some misconception about the scope of mask variables in mind, Currently I don't have any suggestion.